# What are the possible input values of numLevels Wifimanager.calculateSignalLevel method?

Tags: android, signals, wifimanager, rssi

/**
     * Calculates the level of the signal. This should be used any time a signal
     * is being shown.
     *
     * @param rssi The power of the signal measured in RSSI.
     * @param numLevels The number of levels to consider in the calculated
     *            level.
     * @return A level of the signal, given in the range of 0 to numLevels-1
     *         (both inclusive).
     */

```
public static int calculateSignalLevel(int rssi, int numLevels) {
    if (rssi <= MIN_RSSI) {
        return 0;
    } else if (rssi >= MAX_RSSI) {
        return numLevels - 1;
    } else {
        float inputRange = (MAX_RSSI - MIN_RSSI);
        float outputRange = (numLevels - 1);
        return (int)((float)(rssi - MIN_RSSI) * outputRange / inputRange);
    }
}
```

Could any anyone please explain me that  what is the input of numLevels param?
I need to show the Wifi Signal Strength like "good,better,best" based on the output of this method.please help me !!

Answer (score 2):

`numLevels` is literally the number of levels you wish to evaluate the strength of the wifi signal. For instance, a choice of

```
int numLevels = 5;
int strength = calculateSignalLevel(rssi, numLevels);
```

will give you an output range from 0 to 4 (as `numbLevels - 1 = 4`), where 4 is the strongest.

Since you want to evaluate the signal strength on a 'good', 'better', and 'best' scale, you should input `3` as your `numLevels` parameter.